# The shortest distance from the parabola to the straight-line

Tags: conic-sections

Find the shortest distance from the parabola
$$y^2=64x \tag{1}$$  to the straight-line 
$$4x+3y+46=0\tag{2}$$ I guess, to first find 
$$x=-\frac{3y+46}{4}\tag{3}$$
 and than substitue it into the parabola equation, but this way take to much time, moreover i`m not sure that its right, any hints are welcome

Comment: This substitution will compute the intersection of those two. A point on that parabola is of the form $\left[y^2/64, y\right]$ and a distance of a point has a nice formula, so plugging $\left[y^2/64, y\right]$ and finding its minimum (which is a minimum of a quadratic function, hence its stationary point) will give the result.

Comment: From that substitution,I got the equation $y^2+48y+736=0$  where d<0, where i gone wrong?

Comment: As mentioned in my previous comment - this computes the intersection, so it just tells you they don't intersect.

Comment: @pepa.dvorak Ough i totally misunderstand the task, thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that the distance between the parabola $p$ and the line $\ell$ is the length of a segment $PL$ with $P$ lying on the parabola and $L$ lying on the line. Then, by definition of distance, $PL$ is (one of) the shortest segment(s) joining a point on the parabola with a point on the line. In such a case the Pythagorean theorem ensures $PL\perp\ell$: if it weren't so, it would be possible to move a bit $L$ on $\ell$ and decrease the length of $PL$, contra minimality. For a similar reason (convexity), if $\tau$ is the tangent to the parabola at $P$, we also have $\tau\perp PL$, from which $\tau\parallel\ell$, the unicity of $PL$ and $d(p,\ell)=d(\tau,\ell)=d(P,\ell)$ follow.

In our case the slope of $\ell$ is $-\frac{4}{3}$, hence it is enough to find $P\in p$ such that the slope of $\tau$ is $-\frac{4}{3}$.
Through derivatives we have $P=(9,-24)$ and it is easy to finish:
$$ d(P,\ell) = \frac{\left|4\cdot 9-3\cdot 24+46\right|}{\sqrt{3^2+4^2}}=\color{red}{2}.$$

Comment: I see u find a point and compute distance between line and point, but can you pls add more steps on, how to find out that point from parabola, not theory but the derivatives exactly

Comment: All right, that part can be tackled without derivatives, too. Every point on the parabola is associated with a number that gives the slope of the tangent at that point. You may figure out this association by imposing that a discriminant is zero.

Comment: We also have this Lemma dating back to Archimedes: we have a parabola $p$ with vertex at $V$ and some point $P\in p$ with its tangent $\tau$. If $P_1$ is the projection of $P$ on the symmetry axis of the parabola and $P_2$ is the symmetric of $P_1$ with respect to $V$, then $\tau$ goes through $P_2$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Two possible ways to resolve: as an extremal problem, finding minimal value; or geometric approach, as a distance between two parallels where one is a tangent of parabola

Answer (score 0):

Lines parallel to $(2)$ have the equation
$$4x+3y+d=0\tag{4}$$
where $d$ is an arbitrary real number.
If we intersect $(4)$ and the parabola $(1)$ by elimination $x$ we get the equation

$$y^2-48y+16d=0\tag{5}$$
and further
$$y_{1,2}=-24\pm\sqrt{24^2-16d}\tag{6}$$

A line tangent to a parabola has exactly one intersection point with this parabola. So equation $(5)$ must have only one solution.
From $6)$ we see that happens if 
$$24^2-16d=0\tag{7}$$which means that
$$d=36\tag{8}$$
So the tangent is 
$$ 4x+3y+36=0 \tag{9}$$
Substituting $(8)$ in $(6)$ gives 
$$y=-24 \tag{10}$$
and from $(4)$ we get 
$$x=9 \tag{11}$$

So the tangent $(9)$  touches the parabola at the point $(9,-24)$.
Now find the distance of this point from the line $(2)$ and you are done.

Answer (score 0):

Parabola: 
$$y^2=64x\\\frac {dy}{dx}=-\frac {32}y$$

Slope of Line $4x+3y+46=0$ is $-\dfrac 43$.

A point on Parabola closest to Line is the point at which slope of tangent equals the slope of Line, i.e. $(9,-24)$.

Hence shortest distance from Parabola to Line is
$$\frac {4(9)+3(-24)+46}{5}=\color{red}2$$